# A vehicle database in Excel

Tags: performance, beginner, object-oriented, vba, excel

I'm looking for some help. I'm new to coding and have started creating this Vehicle database program in Excel for a friend to use.

He is wanting to be able to  see all vehicles he owns, when registration is due as well as input any vehicle services that have been done.

- I have created a User form in Excel, one for adding a Vehicle and renewing Registration.
- This is working but I believe it isn't very efficient.
- Once I looked into it more and studied it more, I found that you shouldn't put information in the form as such; it is just a presenter and it should be read through modules and classes.
- I have tried doing this and I just get stuck and can't do it or get it to work.  Is this required or is anything else in my coding to be fixed?

Please note that I didn't write the code for the calendar, hidebar or switch off. I can provide the code to them if required.

[image: Vehicle table]
[image: Add Vehicle Form]

### Vehicle Form Code

On the Vehicle form they fill out their Vehicle Details:

- text boxes (Date of purchase, Regonumber, Rego Expiry, Purchase Price, Kms at Purchase, the VIN, Make, Model)
- choices (Year of Vehicle, Colour of Vehicle, Type of Vehicle (Car, Light Rigid, Motorbike etc.), Fuel Type (Unleaded Diesel etc.), Premium Class (to do with our state registration), Transmission Type (Automatic, Manual), Usage Type (whether they use the vehicle for Private or Business)

If they input Purchase price at a date after today it pops up an invalid date warning and makes the textbox red; if the Expiry Date is more than 4 months ago the same thing happens.

- The Purchase Date, (Rego, Expiry - if the Unregistered button isn't ticked), Year, Make, Model, Vehicle Type, Transmission type and Usage is required to be filled out to submit the vehicle to the table.
- When they click Add it adds it to the Table and unloads. If they click Cancel, a message box pops up to confirm, if yes then it just unloads.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, a As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = dropdown
    'hides the address bar at the top
    HideBar Me
    'things to make excel run quicker
    SwitchOff (True)
    With Me
        'Set Form Size
        .Height = 300
        .Width = 364
        'Hide Invalid date warning
        .Invalid_date.Visible = False
        .Invalid_Expiry.Visible = False
        'set Price Format
        .VCH_Price = "$"
        'count every year from this year to 1940 and add to Vechile year list.
        For i = VBA.Year(Now()) To a Step -1
            .VCH_year.AddItem i
            If i = 1940 Then Exit For
        Next
        'create comboboxes from tables on dropdown list page
        .VCH_Fuel.List = ws.Range("Fuel").Value2
        .VCH_Trans.List = ws.Range("Trans").Value2
        .VCH_Body.List = ws.Range("Colour").Value2
        .VCH_Type.List = ws.Range("type").Value2
        .VCH_Usage.List = ws.Range("Usage").Value2
        .VCH_Premium.List = ws.Range("Premium").Value2
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Dim Vehicle_ID As String, result As Boolean
    Set TblVehicle = VehicleSheet.ListObjects("Tbl_Vehicle")
    
    'things to make excel conditions go back to what they were
    SwitchOff (False)
    
    'Loops through all the boxes and check the required are filled in
    result = FrmVehicleCheck(Me)
    If result = False Then MsgBox "missing information", vbInformation:  Exit Sub
    
    'this creates the Vehicle id by adding make, model, body, year and rego together
    Vehicle_ID = VCH_Make & " " & VCH_Model & " " & VCH_Body & " " & VCH_year & " " & VCH_Rego
    'this loads the form onto the Vehicle table
    With TblVehicle.ListRows.Add
        .Range(1) = Vehicle_ID
        .Range(2) = VCH_Rego.value
        .Range(3) = IIf(VCH_Expiry = vbNullString, vbNullString, CDate(VCH_Expiry.value))
        'New rego date column goes here
        If Unregistered.value = True Then .Range(4) = "Yes"
        .Range(5) = VCH_year.value
        .Range(6) = VCH_Make.value
        .Range(7) = VCH_Model.value
        .Range(8) = VCH_Body.value
        .Range(9) = VCH_Vin.value
        .Range(10) = VCH_Trans.value
        .Range(11) = VCH_Fuel.value
        .Range(12) = VCH_Usage.value
        .Range(13) = VCH_Type.value
        .Range(14) = VCH_Premium.value
        .Range(15) = VCH_Kms.value
        .Range(16) = CDate(VCH_date.value)
        .Range(17) = VCH_Price.value
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_click()
    'checks to make sure you want to cance
    Dim result As String
    result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to cancel", vbYesNo)
    If result = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    SwitchOff (False)
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_date_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'when user double clicks on the date it will launch the calendar form then return with the value (picked)
    Launch
    With VCH_date
        .value = (picked)
        .value = VCH_date.value
    End With
    VCH_Rego.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_expiry_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'when user double clicks on the date it will launch the calendar form then return with the value (picked)
    Launch
    With VCH_Expiry
        .value = (picked)
        .value = VCH_Expiry.value
    End With
    VCH_Price.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_make_keypress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    With VCH_Make
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_type_DropButtonClick()
    With VCH_Type
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_usage_DropButtonClick()
    With VCH_Usage
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_trans_DropButtonClick()
    With VCH_Trans
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_model_keypress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    With VCH_Model
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_year_DropButtonClick()
    With VCH_year
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_Rego_keypress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    With VCH_Rego
        If .value = vbNullString Then .BackColor = &H80000005
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_date_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'if purchase date is later than today show error
    With VCH_date
        If IsDate(.value) Then
            If CDate(.value) > Date Then
                Invalid_date.Visible = True
                .BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Else: Invalid_date.Visible = False
                .BackColor = &H80000005
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_expiry_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'if expiry date is before than today show error
    With VCH_Expiry
        If IsDate(.value) Then
            If CDate(.value) < DateAdd("m", -4, Date) Then
                Invalid_Expiry.Visible = True
                .BackColor = &HC0C0FF
            Else: Invalid_Expiry.Visible = False
                .BackColor = &H80000005
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_price_change()
    VCH_Price = Format(VCH_Price, "$###,##")
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_price_KeyPress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'makes it so user can only input numbers in text box and changes them to a $ figure
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Is < vbKey0, Is > vbKey9
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub VCH_kms_KeyPress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'makes it so user can only input numbers in text box
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Is < vbKey0, Is > vbKey9
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub

Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Reset Userform buttons to Inactive Status
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = True
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = True
End Sub

Sub OKButtonInactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Make OK Button appear Green when hovered on
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = True
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = False
End Sub

Sub CancelButtonInactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Make Cancel Button appear Green when hovered on
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = False
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = True
End Sub
```

### Vehicle Module Code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Add_Vehicle_Click()
   
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Vehicle" Then
        Sheets("Vehicle").Activate
        Application.Wait (Now + 0.000006)
    Else: Sheets("Vehicle").Activate
    End If
    Add_Vehicle.Show
End Sub

'checked to make sure all the correct boxes in Add Vehicle are filled in
Public Function FrmVehicleCheck(FrmVehicle As UserForm) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Set ctrl = Nothing
    
    With FrmVehicle
        For Each ctrl In .Controls
            If ctrl.Tag = "*" Then
                If Len(ctrl.Text) = 0 Then
                    If Not ((ctrl.Name = "VCH_Rego" Or _
                       ctrl.Name = "VCH_Expiry") And _
                       .Unregistered.value = True) Then
                        Debug.Print ctrl.Name
                        ctrl.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                        result = ctrl.Name
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next ctrl
    End With
FrmVehicleCheck = IIf(Len(result) = 0, True, False)
    'clearing references
    Set ctrl = Nothing
    Set FrmVehicle = Nothing
End Function
```

[image: Renewal Table]

[image: Registration Renewal form]

[image: Registration Renewal Form filled]

### Registration Renewal

With the Registration Renewal form:

- The ComboBox has the Vehicle registrations from the Vehicle table where the vehicle hasn't been marked as disposed or unregistered and the Vehicle Expiry date is within 4 months of today.
- If they Select either Private or Business it clears all selections and populates the Registration Combobox with the above conditions but also filters and only populates the vehicles relevant to the selection (Private or Business).
- Once a vehicle has been selected then there are 4 Label boxes under the Registration Combobox that populate the information from selected. (I will provide a photo of this). It also populates the Registration Expiry date and makes the renewal period options appear (3 Months, 6 Months, 12 Months).
- Once one of the renewal periods are selected it populates the New Expiry date Label.
- You input the total. If you want to complete more renewals you select the More Renewals tick box.
- You then press Add; it inputs all the data in the Renewals Table and updates the Expiry date in the Vehicles table.
- If the More Renewals box was ticked it returns the form in a cleared state to update another Registration Expiry otherwise it unloads.
- If you  press cancel a warning pops up and if you press okay it unloads.

```
Option Explicit

Private rownum As String, Optmonth As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set FrmRenewal = Me
    Set TblVehicle = [Tbl_Vehicle].ListObject
    Dim Vehicle As New ClsVehicle
    'hide address bar
    HideBar Me
    'make excel run faster
    SwitchOff (True)
    'Run procedure to get Rego data that is has expired less than 4 months ago and due within the next 3 months
    
    Rego_Filtered_Data
    'hide the period selection buttons until a rego is selected
    UpdatePeriods ("Hide")
    'set form size and hide the Period buttons
    With Me
        '.Rego_ID.AddItem Vehicle.Regodue
        .Height = 235
        .Width = 274
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Rego_Bus_Click()
'clear data from form
'filter the Rego ID to only show Business Vehicles
    clearform ("Bus")
    filterusage ("Business")
End Sub

Private Sub Rego_pri_Click()
'clear data from form
'filter the Rego ID to only show Private Vehicles
    clearform ("Pri")
    filterusage ("Private")
End Sub

Private Sub Rego_ID_Click()
    'auto populates Vechicle details and populates vehicle details and expiry dates
    'clear all previous data
    UpdatePeriods
    With Me
        'Attempt to find value in Table's first Column
            rownum = RegoRownum(Rego_ID.value)
            'get data from each column and input into the form
            .Rego_Num.Caption = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 2)
            .Rego_Make.Caption = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 6)
            .Rego_Model.Caption = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 7)
            .Rego_Colour.Caption = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 8)
            .Rego_Expiry.value = Format(TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 3), "DD/MM/YYYY")
        'if the Rego expiry box isnt empty then calculate the Rego renewal periods and input them
        If Not .Rego_Expiry.value = vbNullString Then UpdatePeriods (Rego_Expiry.value)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Set TblRenewal = [Tbl_Renewal].ListObject
    ' if relevent sections arent filled out make them red and return back to form
    If FrmRenewalcheck = False Then MsgBox "missing information", vbInformation: Exit Sub
    'input data into the Renewal table
    With TblRenewal.ListRows.Add
        .Range(1) = Rego_ID.Text
        .Range(2) = Rego_Num.BoundValue
        .Range(3) = Rego_Make.BoundValue
        .Range(4) = Rego_Model.BoundValue
        .Range(5) = CDate(Rego_Expiry.BoundValue)
        .Range(6) = CDate(New_Date.BoundValue)
        .Range(7) = Optmonth
        .Range(8) = Total.value
        .Range(9) = Date
    End With
    'look in the Vehicle table for the Rego ID and input the new expiry date in the New Rego Date field
rownum = RegoRownum(Rego_ID.value)
TblVehicle.DataBodyRange(rownum, 3) = CDate(New_Date.BoundValue)
    'if the more renewals button is pressed restart form, if not clcose form
    If More = True Then
        SwitchOff (False)
        clearform ("Refresh")
        Rego_Filtered_Data
        SwitchOff (True)
        Exit Sub
    Else: Unload Me
    End If
    
    SwitchOff (False)
    'removing references
    Set TblVehicle = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_click()
    'checking you want to cancel
    Dim result As String
    result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to cancel", vbYesNo)
    If result = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    SwitchOff (False)
    Unload Me
    Set TblVehicle = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Option3M_Click()
    'clears the other two Renewal button values and inputs the period renewal date in the new expiry period
    Optmonth = Newperiod("Option3M")
End Sub

Private Sub Option6M_Click()
    'clears the other two Renewal button values and inputs the period renewal date in the new expiry period
    Optmonth = Newperiod("Option6M")
End Sub

Private Sub Option12M_Click()
    'clears the other two Renewal button values and inputs the period renewal date in the new expiry period
    Optmonth = Newperiod("Option12M")
End Sub

Private Sub Total_change()
    Total = Format(Total, "$###,##")
End Sub

Private Sub Total_KeyPress( _
        ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'makes it so user can only input numbers in text box and changes them to a $ figure
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case Is < vbKey0, Is > vbKey9
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub

Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Reset Userform buttons to Inactive Status
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = True
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = True
End Sub

Sub OKButtonInactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Make OK Button appear Green when hovered on
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = True
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = False
End Sub

Sub CancelButtonInactive_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'PURPOSE: Make Cancel Button appear Green when hovered on
    CancelButtonInactive.Visible = False
    OKButtonInactive.Visible = True
End Sub
```

### Renewal module

```
Option Explicit
Sub Rego_Renewal_Click()
    Rego_Renewal.Show
End Sub
Global TblVehicle As ListObject, TblRenewal As ListObject, FrmRenewal As MSForms.UserForm

Dim ctrl As Control, rowNumbers() As Long ' Array to store row numbers

Sub Rego_Filtered_Data()
    Dim RngRego As Range: Set RngRego = TblVehicle.ListColumns("Vehicle ID").DataBodyRange
    Dim RngExpiry As Range:  Set RngExpiry = TblVehicle.ListColumns("Rego expiry").DataBodyRange
    Dim RngDisposed As Range: Set RngDisposed = TblVehicle.ListColumns("Disposal Date").DataBodyRange
    Dim x As Long, rw As Long
    Dim StrRego_filtered As String
  
    Dim beforedate As Date, afterdate As Date
    beforedate = DateAdd("m", 4, Date)
    afterdate = DateAdd("m", -4, Date)
    
    x = 1
    'look for registrations that expired 4 months ago to due in the next 4 months and return in a combobox
    'if vehicle is marked as disposed then skip and dont show in renewal
    If Not IsEmpty(RngDisposed.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
        For rw = RngRego.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Select Case RngExpiry.Cells(rw, 1)
                Case afterdate To beforedate
                    StrRego_filtered = RngRego.Cells(rw, 1).value
                    Debug.Print StrRego_filtered
                    Debug.Print RngExpiry.Cells(rw, 1).value
                    With FrmRenewal.Rego_ID
                        .AddItem StrRego_filtered
                        .ColumnCount = 1
                    End With
                    ReDim Preserve rowNumbers(1 To x)
                    rowNumbers(x) = rw
                    x = x + 1
            End Select
            Debug.Print rw
        Next rw
    End If
    Debug.Print StrRego_filtered
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Function FrmRenewalcheck() As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim Counta As Byte
     Set ctrl = Nothing
    Counta = 0
        For Each ctrl In FrmRenewal.Controls
            With ctrl
                Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
                    Case "ComboBox"
                        If .ListIndex = -1 Then
                            .BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                            Debug.Print .Name
                            result = .Name
                        End If
                    Case "Label"
                        If .Name = "New_Date" And .Caption = vbNullString Then
                            .BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                            Debug.Print .Name
                            result = .Name
                        End If
                    Case "OptionButton"
                        If .GroupName = "Period" And .value = False Then
                        If Left(.Name, 6) = "Option" Then Counta = Counta + 1
                            If Counta = 3 Then
                                With FrmRenewal
                                    .Option3M.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                    .Option6M.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                    .Option12M.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                                    result = ctrl.Name
                                    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
                                End With
                            End If
                        End If
                    Case "TextBox"
                        If Len(.Text) = 0 Then
                            .BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                            Debug.Print .Name
                            result = .Name
                        End If
                End Select
            End With
        Next ctrl
  FrmRenewalcheck = IIf(Len(result) = 0, True, False)
    'clearing references
    Set ctrl = Nothing
End Function

Function Newperiod(OpName As String) As String
    Dim SelPeriod As String
    'initialise
    Set ctrl = Nothing
    'loop controls looking for option button that is
    'both true and part of input GroupName
    For Each ctrl In FrmRenewal.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case Is = "OptionButton"
                If ctrl.GroupName = "Period" Then
                        If ctrl.Name = OpName Then
                            ctrl.value = True
                            SelPeriod = Replace(OpName, "Option", "Rego_")
                            FrmRenewal.New_Date = FrmRenewal.Controls.Item(SelPeriod)
                            Newperiod = SelPeriod
                            FrmRenewal.Total = vbNullString
                        Else: ctrl.value = False
                        End If
                End If
        End Select
    Next ctrl
    'clear references
     Set ctrl = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub clearform(proc As String)
 Set ctrl = Nothing
    For Each ctrl In FrmRenewal.Controls
        With ctrl
            Select Case .Tag
                Case Is = "clear"
                    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
                        Case Is = "TextBox"
                            .value = vbNullString
                            .BackColor = &H80000005
                        Case Is = "ComboBox"
                            .Clear
                            .BackColor = &H80000005
                        Case Is = "Label"
                            .Caption = vbNullString
                            .BackColor = &H80000005
                        Case Is = "OptionButton"
                            .Visible = False
                            .value = False
                            .BackColor = &H80000005
                        Case Is = "CheckBox"
                            .value = False
                            .BackColor = &H80000005
                    End Select
                Case Is = vbNullString
                    If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" And proc = "Refresh" Then .value = False: .BackColor = &H80000005
            End Select
        End With
    Next ctrl
    Set ctrl = Nothing
End Sub

Function filterusage(Opttype As String)
    Dim filteredRows() As Range ' Array to store filtered rows
    Dim finalRowCount As Long
    Dim StrRego_filteredUsage As String
    Dim i As Long ' Variable to iterate through the row numbers array
    
    ' Loop through the row numbers array
    For i = LBound(rowNumbers) To UBound(rowNumbers)
        ' Access the corresponding row in the table using the row number
        Dim currentRow As Range
        Set currentRow = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange.Rows(rowNumbers(i))
        
        ' Check if another column meets the additional criteria
        Dim rngUsage As Range
        Set rngUsage = currentRow.Cells(, 12) ' Replace columnNumber with the desired column index
        
        ' Apply additional filtering based on the criteria
        If rngUsage.value = Opttype Then
            ' Add the filtered row to the array
            Dim RngRego As Range
            Set RngRego = TblVehicle.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
            StrRego_filteredUsage = RngRego.Cells(rowNumbers(i), 1).value
            Debug.Print StrRego_filteredUsage
                With FrmRenewal.Rego_ID
                    .AddItem StrRego_filteredUsage
                    .ColumnCount = 1
                End With
            ReDim Preserve filteredRows(1 To finalRowCount + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Function RegoRownum(VehicleID As String) As Long
 Dim FoundCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FoundCell = TblVehicle.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(VehicleID, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then RegoRownum = _
                        TblVehicle.ListRows(FoundCell.Row - TblVehicle.HeaderRowRange.Row).index
End Function

Function UpdatePeriods(Optional NewVal As String) As Long
    With FrmRenewal
        Select Case NewVal
            Case Is = vbNullString
                .Option3M.value = False
                .Option6M.value = False
                .Option12M.value = False
                .Rego_3M = vbNullString
                .Rego_6M = vbNullString
                .Rego_12M = vbNullString
                .New_Date = vbNullString
            Case Is = "Hide"
                .Option3M.Visible = False
                .Option6M.Visible = False
                .Option12M.Visible = False
                .Rego_3M = vbNullString
                .Rego_6M = vbNullString
                .Rego_12M = vbNullString
                .New_Date = vbNullString
            Case Else
                .Rego_3M.Caption = DateAdd("m", 3, NewVal)
                .Option3M.Visible = True
                .Rego_6M.Caption = DateAdd("m", 6, NewVal)
                .Option6M.Visible = True
                .Rego_12M.Caption = DateAdd("m", 12, NewVal)
                .Option12M.Visible = True
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @Greedo I have no idea how to add an example of the workbook. I have updated the post to provide further information about the forms

Comment: @Greedo https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ie80ndy2l900m0r6c2n8j/Example.xlsm?rlkey=lbwyufxj15pg1m2e737ippbp9&dl=0 Let me know if this works

Comment: Consider using Excel's PC sibling, MS Access, which is actually a database and ships with user interface forms (even report generator) to add/edit/delete records without any code to start!